# How to update/change/empty data in txtbox without showing error

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, keypress, textchanged

I am working a small sale invoice application on WF. I have a customer table and a product table. Then, I populate customer name and product name via comboboxes on Sale-form. Once user selects an item from ProductName combobox, other textboxes like Price and ProductID are auto-populated with data from Product Table from database. I have also a textbox named txtQuantity that can be entered for Quantity for product order. Once a number is entered for Quantity, subtotal, GST(which is Tax in Singapore), and total are auto-calculated and those values appear on textboxes of Subtotal, GST and Total. When a user delete quantity to update/change, it shows error as "Format Exception was unhanded, input string was not in a correct format". I like to prevent this error to stop working my application when user delete quantity or want to change to a new value. How do I go about it because I am complete lost here. Below is my code.

```
private void txtQuantity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int iQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text);

   decimal dPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrice.Text);

   decimal dSubtotal = dPrice * iQuantity;
   decimal dGST = dSubtotal * 7/100;
   decimal dTotal = dSubtotal + dGST;

    txtSubTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(dSubtotal);
    txtGST.Text = Convert.ToString(dGST);
    txtTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(dTotal);

}
```

I also wanted to set parameters for quantity textbox as only for entering numbers. I will do that later. This is going to be another thing to explore. Any advice for this is also welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: You need to learn how to debug, so you will be able to find the row, which throws exception and understand for yourself what is going wrong. My guess is what `txtQuantity` or `txtPrice` are blank and your `Convert` function fails. You could simply check those before doing anything (use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`).

Comment: You should be using `int.TryParse` and `decimal.TryParse` to see if the data is compatible with the data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would run all of your string inputs through the following (or something similar) before trying to assign them to an integer variable, especially when dealing with direct user input.

```
string myVar1;

//Something that assigns a value to myVar1

if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(myVar1))
{
 myVar1 = "0";
}
else
{
  int number;
  bool result = Int32.TryParse(myVar1, out number);
  if (result)
  {
     //you have a valid input and valid parse, do whatever you need with number     variable     
  }
  else
  {
    //bad input, reset to blank and show error message
  }
```

}

*Note the above code is an example and while fairly close to what you probably want, you will need to modify it before just copy/pasting it into your application*

Comment: Thank for your sample code. I had figured it out based on your code. It is working fine now. Now, I am going to explore more how to do calculate Quantity in textbox against Quantity in Table. I have Quantity in Product Table. Quantity from textbox will check against Quantity in Product Table to see if there are adequate stock to make sale. If so, that quantity including other items will be saved in Sale Table.  I haven't coded yet. I still need to do research on it.Any guidenance on this matter, please.

Comment: Not sure what your asking, if you have both quantities you should be able to check whether they are equal, or if one is less than or greater than the other